# Proving simple inequality with four variables

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Assume we have four variabes, $ 0 \leq \beta_1, \beta_2, \lambda_1, \lambda_2 \leq 1 $, and that $\beta_1 \geq \beta_2$ and $\lambda_1 \geq \lambda_2$. Then the following inequality holds:
$$\beta_1 (\lambda_1 - \sqrt\lambda_1 \sqrt\lambda_2) + \beta_2 (\lambda_2 - \sqrt\lambda_1 \sqrt\lambda_2) \geq 0.$$

How can I prove this analytically? I know it's true from numerical simulation, but I can't figure out how to show it.

Comment: It's true without the $\le 1$ constraint as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\beta_1 (\lambda_1 - \sqrt\lambda_1 \sqrt\lambda_2) + \beta_2 (\lambda_2 - \sqrt\lambda_1 \sqrt\lambda_2) =(\beta_1\sqrt\lambda_1-\beta_2\sqrt\lambda_2)(\sqrt\lambda_1-\sqrt\lambda_2) \geq 0$$

Comment: Yes, of course! I knew I was missing something obvious. Many thanks!